# Report with table join Devexpress Reports

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress Report to create a report showing the Chart of Accounts.  see attached photos, when report runs it seems that the grouping is off by 1???  not sure why.  also a photo of the tables i have for this. i have attached my code also. thanks in advance for the error correction i may have done!!

[image: Database tables]

[image: Report print out]

```
  ' Create a data source with the required connection parameters.  
   Dim connectionParameters As New Access97ConnectionParameters("../../Act2024.rjd", "", "****")
   Dim ds As New SqlDataSource(connectionParameters)

'Add the query to the data source.
 Dim query As SelectQuery = SelectQueryFluentBuilder.AddTable("tblChartOfAccounts").SortBy("ChartAcctsNo").Join("tblChartOfAccountsDescripton", "ChartAcctsID").SelectAllColumns().Build("tblChartOfAccounts")

'add the query to the collection and return the data source. 
query.Name = "rptQuery"
ds.Queries.Add(query)
Me.DataSource = ds
Me.DataMember = "rptQuery"

 LblChartAcctsNo.ExpressionBindings.Add(New ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", "[ChartAcctsNo]"))
 LblAcctGroupName.ExpressionBindings.Add(New ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", "[AcctGroupName]"))

 LblDescChartAcctsNo.ExpressionBindings.Add(New ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", "[ChartAcctsDescNo]"))
 LblChartAcctsDesc.ExpressionBindings.Add(New ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", "[ChartAcctsDesc]"))

Dim groupField As New GroupField With {
.FieldName = "ChartAcctsNo",
.SortOrder = XRColumnSortOrder.Ascending
 }
 GhAccounts.GroupFields.Add(groupField)

LblChartOfAccounts.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
LblChartOfAccounts.ForeColor = Color.White

Detail.SortFields.Add(New GroupField("ChartAcctsDescNo"))
```